# Convert from java to TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Thought that it will be an easy, but appears to be complicated (for me). Could someone, please, help to find correct solution for following:
Have 200 tests inside one package **selenium.tests.postTip** which looks like this one below:

```
package selenium.tests.postTip;

import java.util.List;
import selenium.BaseTest;
import selenium.DriverBase;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PostBadmintonOddEven extends DriverBase {

@Test
public void main() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = BaseTest.login();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    List<WebElement> allSports = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='be-sportpicker__list']//div[@class='be-sport-thumb__title be-typo-be']"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/be-root/main//be-scroller//be-sportpicker//ul[@class='be-sportpicker__list']/li/a[contains(@href,\"/badminton\")]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    BaseTest.betTypeOddEvenFullEvent(driver);

  }
 }
```

Since that I have to run those tests as a single test (which already works perfectly) and as a Suite, my question is:
How can I achieve to create (I tried with one **xml** file without any success) TestNG suite with all tests in it. Tried to run all of them, but only first can run, rest of them not. What am I doing wrong?

*Note: BaseTest method which I am calling on last line, doing data check and finish when loop (for loop) finishes.*
I tried with following in above test without success to start second test (aomost same as shown above):

```
@AfterTest
driver.quit();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? Also you can use packages attribute in testng.xml. Refer to this - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml the second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is naming your test class and methods incorrectly. Rename your test class so that it should have ***Test*** label either in *prefix* or *suffix*. Also you have annotated main method with @Test annotation. Main method is defacto entry point from where JVM starts. Use custom names for methods , that describes the test method.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could not figure out what I am doing incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @AfterTest method, you can check with @AfterMethod

If that's not solve, 
What do you use to get all tests, in TestNG ? @DataProvider with dynamic Array or Excel !